# Can I install the Facebook SDK on a mac running OSX10.6.8?

Tags: facebook, macos, sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

I downloaded the Facebook iPhone sdk 3.0 on my mac where im developing my iPhone game but the installation failed two times. Is this because I have 10.6.8 on my computer?

Here's the message I got

[image: The installation failed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install the SDK on OS 10.6.8. I have just installed it myself and there were no problems.

I believe all the package does is place the SDK in your Documents folder. So, really you could just take the repo https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk yourself and install wherever you wish.

Comment: Awesome I got it. One more quick question, how do I add it to my project? I'm using kobold2d so my project is in that workspace and im not sure how to add the sdk to my project

Answer (score 0):

I've just get the same error and solution (in my case) was simple: re-download sdk ;)